# Android drawable xml: Draw an arrow

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable

I have been trying to create the following arrow, but shorter, without the tail and pointing down. But to no avail.

Can someone help me here? I'm stuck and can't figure it out. Do I need to create the shape in code instead of XML or am I just failing at creating the proper XML.

I felt there was no need to post my code since it's really not any different from the code found when visiting the link.

[Android triangle (arrow) defined as an XML shape](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/android-triangle-arrow-defined-as-an-xml-shape/)

[image: Arrow]

Comment: why not use image rather?

Comment: I could, but when supporting all screen sizes and having to create the same image for all sizes, seemed like a lot of effort since I'm better at coding than creating images. Also I liked customizability of the XML variant.

Comment: you have to create only the biggest one and downscaling for the other resolutions. I think that's not a big deal

Comment: Yeah. A 9-patch may be the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The NinePatch class permits drawing a bitmap in nine or more sections.
>   Essentially, it allows the creation of custom graphics that will scale
>   the way that you define.

Take a look at here
http://developer-dot-android.blogspot.com.es/2012/03/android-9-patch-image-tutorial.html
and here
http://blog.fenrir-inc.com/us/2012/02/android-design-enlarge-images-with-nine-patch.html

to understand how to do a 9patch image.

Then, you can create your arrow with any graphic program (i.e. photoshop) and use [this online tool](http://draw9patch.com/#url=http://draw9patch.com/image/btn.png&top%5B%5D=25&top%5B%5D=50&right%5B%5D=25&right%5B%5D=50&bottom%5B%5D=25&bottom%5B%5D=50&left%5B%5D=25&left%5B%5D=50) or the [official SDK tool](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) to make it stretchable

Comment: I will accept this as an answer if nobody wants to try and make the XML drawable.

Comment: did you find a better solution?

Comment: No I did not. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work to get you an upward facing arrow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="-40%"
            android:pivotY="87%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                <stroke android:color="@color/transparent" android:width="10dp"/>
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/your_color_here" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Found: https://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/android-triangle-arrow-defined-as-an-xml-shape/